# What is the `installd` process, and why is it eating my CPU?

Tags: activity-monitor, macos

My MacBook is frying my lap, and the CPU monitor is going crazy: over 200% CPU being used by a process named `installd`.

What is it?  Can I kill it?

Comment: 200%?, check the status of your RAM,s!

Comment: Sometimes CPU goes wild if something else is not responding. Like the RAM or the Hard Disk, so check those for high activity.

Comment: In addition to the good advice from Lauri Ranta - the installer program should also be running, and you can click on it's icon from the Dock and then press command L and command 3 to summon the install log file and enable all messages to be shown. You would expect to see pertinent install process while CPU is above 100% and consider killing the installer / looking deeper for error messages in the install log (Console app will show that log file as well once the installer exits).

Comment: Don't kill it.  It's most likely the software update is running background (it could be other installation tho).  Also the reason why CPU goes up beyond 100% is that you have multi-core CPU.  My Mac has 4 cores so it could go as high as 400%.

Comment: Kenji is right on.  I came to this page when my installd did the same thing.  While I was reading, it finally stopped, and then i was immediately given the "updates available" notification.  Why this process needs all available CPU on a quad-core i7 for several minutes is another question.

Comment: Mine is 461%, it's crazy

Comment: My concern is the RAM usage. It is using 3.76 GB. Neither App Store or System Preferences is open, nor have I done updates to anything for days.

Comment: So, my 3.76 RAM stayed there Even after I turned off Auto Update and finally went away when I rebooted. I aim imagining that this supposed 3.76 GB of RAM was old and was still cached or something from the time I updated Xcode days ago. Not sure if it impacted system performance, but doubt it.

Answer (score 128):

This is a daemon which is part of **PackageKit framework** and it's usually running as a background process for the **"Software Update" GUI application**.
For example, if you open the **Software Update** application and check for updates, take a look at the Activity Monitor--you'll see the "installd" process doing a bunch of work.

The reason it pegs your CPU is because it must compile the current list of software installed on your computer, and compare with the current version list received from Apple's servers.

You can set the frequency of Software Update checks in System Preferences and Software Update.

The default settings are both to "Check for updates" and "Download updates automatically".
You may adjust either setting, but I would not recommend turning it off altogether.

There's **nothing wicked about this process** - it's just set to download updates.

You can solve your CPU problem by lowering the priority of the process or by just killing the process in Activity Monitor.

---

Technical information:

The location in Lion OSX is in:
`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Resources/installd`

(if you have `locate` configured correctly, run: `locate installd` to find the right location).

Comment: How do you set the priority of a process?

Comment: You can use `renice` command to change the priority for the process.

Comment: Note that `renice` will lower the priority of a process but won't stop it from using all available CPU.  If no other program is asking for CPU time, the system will still give all available CPU to the `installd` process.

Comment: On Mac OS 10.10.1, this setting is under System Preferences -> App Store. Looks like they re-enabled it without telling me when I upgraded to Yosemite.

Comment: You don't need to use `locate` on macOS.  Use `mdfind -name installd` instead, it uses Spotlight and is always available.

Comment: installd seems to take a constant average of about10% of CPU (according to top) when it's simply waiting for you to restart to finish an update.

Answer (score 16):

It's normally run when you for example install an App Store application or remove an application from Launchpad. It shouldn't stay running in the background or keep using that much CPU though. You can probably just force quit it from Activity Monitor or run `sudo killall -9 installd`.

The binary is in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Resources/installd` in 10.8.

Comment: So, the question is, how long has it been doing this?

Comment: For me, several minutes, and then it went down, and then it started going again (even though I didn't install anything), and then it went down again.  It's gone for now, but who knows if it'll return.

Comment: You could also run `sudo opensnoop -n installd` to see what files the processes access or search for installd in Console.

Comment: Don't just `kill -9` a process. `SIGKILL` should be a last resort, since the process does not necessarily terminate in a well-defined or consistent state. Always try `-15` (`SIGTERM`– terminate) and `-6` (`SIGABRT` – abort process) first.

Comment: @user495470 `opensnoop` does not work for me. I get `dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 5 (ID 172: syscall::open:return): invalid user access in action #11 at DIF offset 24`.

Answer (score 7):

It's Apple's install process.

What's annoying is:

1. Apple haven't (as yet) made this less CPU-intensive OR given you the option to do so. Note that the CPU-intensive stage is only at the initial part of the install and does stop.
2. you can't quickly see the progress of the Downloads

You can see progress but need to do the following:

```
Apple logo (top left) > App Store > Updates and click Update.
```

This will then reveal a progress bar with the current download state.

Answer (score 5):

I used Activity Monitor to kill the process at once. And so:

- CPU returned back to normal;
- A notification from App Store showed up in Notification Center asking for when to install updates.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see *exactly* what `installd` (the "Software Update" GUI application) is doing, watch what files it's touching:

```bash
sudo lsof -p $(pgrep -x installd)
```

it's convenient to wrap that in a `while` loop to watch what's going on (`while true; do <the above>; sleep 2; done`).

> ```bash
> COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF                NODE NAME
> installd 33160 root  cwd    DIR   1,18      640                   2 /
> installd 33160 root  txt    REG   1,18   170768 1152921500312275954 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/installd
> installd 33160 root  txt    REG   1,18    51268           120667156 /Library/Preferences/Logging/.plist-cache.YFQq27g8
> installd 33160 root  txt    REG   1,18   129672           124323933 /private/var/db/analyticsd/events.allowlist
> installd 33160 root  txt    REG   1,18   234832            97228994 /private/var/db/timezone/tz/2022g.1.0/icutz/icutz44l.dat
> installd 33160 root  txt    REG   1,18    32768           117755779 /private/var/db/mds/messages/se_SecurityMessages
> installd 33160 root  txt    REG   1,18  1763679 1152921500312170469 /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SecErrorMessages.loctable
> installd 33160 root  txt    REG   1,18    61010 1152921500312170467 /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SecDebugErrorMessages.strings
> installd 33160 root  txt    REG   1,18 30407360 1152921500312435095 /usr/share/icu/icudt70l.dat
> installd 33160 root    0r   CHR    3,2      0t0                 341 /dev/null
> installd 33160 root    1u   CHR    3,2      0t0                 341 /dev/null
> installd 33160 root    2u   CHR    3,2      0t0                 341 /dev/null
> ```

you can also look at its log:

```bash
sudo log show --info --predicate "process == 'installd'"
```

will spit out stuff like:

> ```
> 2023-03-31 19:11:21.594332-0700 0x113d531  Activity    0x1b55bf3            37396  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustSettingsXPCRead
> 2023-03-31 19:11:21.599929-0700 0x113d531  Activity    0x1b55bf4            37396  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-03-31 19:11:21.660048-0700 0x113d531  Default     0x0                  37396  0    installd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:SecError] Trust evaluate failure: [leaf ExtendedKeyUsage] [ca1 IntermediateEKU]
> 2023-03-31 19:11:21.660268-0700 0x113d531  Activity    0x1b55bf5            37396  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-03-31 19:11:21.664108-0700 0x113d531  Default     0x0                  37396  0    installd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:mds] Recording an MDS plugin: /System/Library/Security/ldapdl.bundle {87191ca6-0fc9-11d4-849a-000502b52122}
> 2023-03-31 19:11:21.664189-0700 0x113d531  Default     0x0                  37396  0    installd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:mds] Recording an MDS plugin: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework {87191ca0-0fc9-11d4-849a-000502b52122}
> 2023-03-31 19:11:21.724084-0700 0x113c55c  Error       0x0                  37396  0    installd: (Metadata) [com.apple.metadata:Metadata] unable to get a dev_t for store 1795162192.
> 2023-03-31 19:11:21.730298-0700 0x113c55c  Activity    0x1b55bf6            37396  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-03-31 19:11:21.733041-0700 0x113c55c  Activity    0x1b55bf7            37396  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-03-31 19:11:21.735240-0700 0x113c55c  Default     0x0                  37396  0    installd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:SecError] Trust evaluate failure: [leaf ExtendedKeyUsage] [ca1 IntermediateEKU]
> 2023-03-31 19:11:21.735330-0700 0x113c55c  Activity    0x1b55bf8            37396  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-03-31 19:11:21.968902-0700 0x113c55c  Activity    0x1b55bf9            37396  0    installd: (CoreFoundation) Loading Preferences From System CFPrefsD
> 2023-03-31 20:03:13.126812-0700 0x115502a  Activity    0x1b55bfa            37396  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-03-31 20:03:13.133388-0700 0x115502a  Activity    0x1b55bfb            37396  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-03-31 20:03:13.138923-0700 0x115502a  Default     0x0                  37396  0    installd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:SecError] Trust evaluate failure: [leaf ExtendedKeyUsage] [ca1 IntermediateEKU]
> 2023-03-31 20:03:13.139094-0700 0x115502a  Activity    0x1b55bfc            37396  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-03-31 20:03:13.207376-0700 0x115503a  Activity    0x1b55bfd            37396  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-03-31 20:03:13.211029-0700 0x115503a  Activity    0x1b55bfe            37396  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-03-31 20:03:13.215457-0700 0x115503a  Default     0x0                  37396  0    installd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:SecError] Trust evaluate failure: [leaf ExtendedKeyUsage] [ca1 IntermediateEKU]
> 2023-03-31 20:03:13.215628-0700 0x115503a  Activity    0x1b55bff            37396  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-04-01 06:49:21.910186-0700 0x12583ad  Default     0x0                  45718  0    installd: (CacheDelete) [com.apple.cache_delete:client] Registered: com.apple.installd.CacheDelete, result: 0
> 2023-04-01 11:46:21.984952-0700 0x12c93b3  Default     0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CacheDelete) [com.apple.cache_delete:client] Registered: com.apple.installd.CacheDelete, result: 0
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.169598-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Daemon status changed from 0 to 1
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.170246-0700 0x12cb3dc  Default     0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Received configuration update from daemon (initial)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.170591-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CarbonCore) [com.apple.CarbonCore:coreservicesdaemon] SCSession():SCSession( id=100, this=0x0x14b823b10 option=65538) created, forUID=0 mach_port_t=0x3807.
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.170607-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CarbonCore) [com.apple.CarbonCore:coreservicesdaemon] SCSession():SCSession( id=101, this=0x0x14b823300 option=65538) created, forUID=0 mach_port_t=0x3603.
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.170609-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CarbonCore) [com.apple.CarbonCore:coreservicesdaemon] connectToCoreServicesD():Instantiating server (coreservicesd based) SCSession, port=0x3807 serverOptions=0x10002.
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.171199-0700 0x12cb3db  Activity    0x1c3caa0            33160  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.175699-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Dropping com.apple.security.LegacyAPICounts as it isn\'t used in any transform (not in the config or budgeted?)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.175838-0700 0x12cb3db  Default     0x0                  33160  0    installd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:trustsettings] TrustSettingsUseXPC is enabled (via feature flags)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.175839-0700 0x12cb3db  Activity    0x1c3caa1            33160  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustSettingsXPCRead
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.176879-0700 0x12cb3db  Activity    0x1c3caa2            33160  0    installd: (Security) SecKeychainAddCallback
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.177093-0700 0x12cb3db  Activity    0x1c3caa3            33160  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustSettingsXPCRead
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.181727-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Dropping com.apple.security.LegacyAPICounts as it isn't used in any transform (not in the config or budgeted?)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.188072-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Dropping com.apple.security.LegacyAPICounts as it isn't used in any transform (not in the config or budgeted?)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.188082-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Dropping com.apple.security.LegacyAPICounts as it isn't used in any transform (not in the config or budgeted?)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.188175-0700 0x12cb3db  Activity    0x1c3caa4            33160  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.246625-0700 0x12cb3db  Default     0x0                  33160  0    installd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:SecError] Trust evaluate failure: [leaf ExtendedKeyUsage] [ca1 IntermediateEKU]
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.246687-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Dropping com.apple.security.LegacyAPICounts as it isn't used in any transform (not in the config or budgeted?)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.246969-0700 0x12cb3db  Activity    0x1c3caa5            33160  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.250494-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Dropping com.apple.security.LegacyAPICounts as it isn't used in any transform (not in the config or budgeted?)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.252298-0700 0x12cb3db  Default     0x0                  33160  0    installd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:mds] Recording an MDS plugin: /System/Library/Security/ldapdl.bundle {87191ca6-0fc9-11d4-849a-000502b52122}
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.252344-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Dropping com.apple.security.LegacyMDSPluginCounts as it isn't used in any transform (not in the config or budgeted?)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.252418-0700 0x12cb3db  Default     0x0                  33160  0    installd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:mds] Recording an MDS plugin: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework {87191ca0-0fc9-11d4-849a-000502b52122}
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.252422-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Dropping com.apple.security.LegacyMDSPluginCounts as it isn't used in any transform (not in the config or budgeted?)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.257843-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Dropping com.apple.security.LegacyAPICounts as it isn't used in any transform (not in the config or budgeted?)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.260858-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Dropping com.apple.security.LegacyAPICounts as it isn't used in any transform (not in the config or budgeted?)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.260892-0700 0x12cb3db  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Dropping com.apple.security.LegacyAPICounts as it isn't used in any transform (not in the config or budgeted?)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.318949-0700 0x12c93b6  Error       0x0                  33160  0    installd: (Metadata) [com.apple.metadata:Metadata] unable to get a dev_t for store 1795162192.
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.324567-0700 0x12c93b6  Info        0x0                  33160  0    installd: (CoreAnalytics) [com.apple.CoreAnalytics:client] Dropping com.apple.security.LegacyAPICounts as it isn't used in any transform (not in the config or budgeted?)
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.326005-0700 0x12c93b6  Activity    0x1c3caa6            33160  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.330049-0700 0x12c93b6  Activity    0x1c3caa7            33160  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.333097-0700 0x12c93b6  Default     0x0                  33160  0    installd: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:SecError] Trust evaluate failure: [leaf ExtendedKeyUsage] [ca1 IntermediateEKU]
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.333213-0700 0x12c93b6  Activity    0x1c3caa8            33160  0    installd: (Security) SecTrustEvaluateIfNecessary
> 2023-04-01 11:49:29.598241-0700 0x12c93b6  Activity    0x1c3caa9            33160  0    installd: (CoreFoundation) Loading Preferences From System CFPrefsD
> ```

interpreting any of this, of course, is its own question.

Comment: `watch` is not included in macOS (anymore?) so you may need to install it. For example: `brew install watch`.

Comment: DAMN! So close to something that had no onerous dependencies. tbh let me edit this so it doesn't use `watch`

Answer (score 0):

Mine was installd and storeagent - so I just killed them:

```
sudo killall -9 installd
sudo killall -9 storeagent
```

Comment: What is the impact of killing these? Does it crash or corrupt anything?

Comment: Mac OS X installers typically do lengthy operations (unpacking, compiling) on install files in a temporary location, and spend relatively little time actually moving the files into place. You can see this for yourself if you run an installer that reports its progress. This suggests that there is a unlikely but existent chance it might leave your system in an inconsistent state. In addition, the last step of install is writing a "install completed" receipt, so if that doesn't get written, it'll just probably try to install the software again later, fixing the inconsistency.

Comment: Also, I believe the super risky can-leave-your-system-dead-if-killed updates are the ones that require restart and install only when all users are logged out.

Comment: There's no real guarantee what will happen if you shoot down a process like this. Probably nothing, but you may corrupt something, so try other signals before killing with `-9`.

Answer (score -8):

Installd is a process run by Sophos anti virus. The process is called by InterCheck which is a process related to Sophos's active scanning.

Comment: acutally it seems to be a core component of the operating system that is launched after you authenticate the `Installer` program to perform an installation. There are issues of it creeping up to hog too much CPU power for some users of Sophos AV for Mac. Edit your answer so that it is suggested as a possibility, one of many, and you'll probably get some upvotes.