# What to do with the persistent `installd` process?

Tags: mac-mini

My `installd` process is eating up 2.61GB of RAM memory on my Mac Mini M1. [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/87109/75922) says `App Store` will show which updates are running. But my App Store -> Updates shows there is no update.

Comment: If you're not installing anything, I'd just kill it.